# subversion server import remote server

Tags: svn, import, ftp

I have a subversion server running with a repository at /srv/repos/project.

What i like to do is import all the files from a remote webserver.
How can i do this, i have tried to use the import command.

svn import http://www.domain.nl/ file://srv/repos/svn/project -m "first import"

The problem is of course that i can't access the http:// protocol, but can i use for example a ftp connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two steps:

- download the files from remote webserver by FTP and place them into your repo as plain unversioned files;
- do `svn import` of your local downloaded files.

Answer (score 0):

checkout [rsvndump](http://rsvndump.sourceforge.net/)

Also look at this [blog](http://blog.sourcehosting.net/2008/11/03/dump-remote-subversion-repository/) for some sample usage

Answer (score 0):

You could use FTP, or SCP to accomplish this. HTTP can not work, as there is no method in HTTP to query all accessible files, which means subversion doesn't know what files it should retrieve. The simplest of all solutions is download the files (e.g. by using scp), then add them to subversion, and commit.

- scp -r username@remote.host.com:/directory/ ./local/
- svn add ./local/*
- svn commit -m "Adding all pre-existing files."